# Is there something like `time` that also records I/O and CPU?

Tags: command, time, statistics, time-utility

I can pretty quickly monitor the running time of a process with `time`:

```
x@y ~ $ time foo

real        0m14.299s
user        0m4.770s
sys         0m0.440s
```

Is there a way I can get the same data for I/O and CPU usage of an argument, recorded to STDOUT? A simple command or utility like `time` would be ideal, where I just pass the argument of the thing I want to run:

```
x@y ~ $ stats foo

wallclock runtime     0m14.299s
I/O reads             290,420 KB
I/O writes            239,429 KB
peak CPU usage        18.62%
mean CPU usage        1.44%
# etc.
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

look at the time man page on your system, some implementations have format options to include I/O, CPU and Memory stats (-f).

For instance, GNU `time`, with `-v` will show all available info (here on Linux):

```
/usr/bin/time -v ls

Command being timed: "ls"
User time (seconds): 0.00
System time (seconds): 0.00
Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 3664
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 273
Voluntary context switches: 2
Involuntary context switches: 2
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 0
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

On `BSDs`, use `-l` instead.

Note that this is the actual `/usr/bin/time` program, not the keyword that some shells like `bash` provide which you invoke with `time pipeline`.

Comment: `zsh`'s `time` keyword can also be configured (with `$TIMEFMT`) to provide with that information.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Perfect! Also, thank you to the editors of this post who clarified that you'll need to run it with `command time -v ...` since `bash` is hijacking `time`.

Answer (score 4):

The command `strace` can be useful, you can limit the trace to only count `-c` or a subset of system calls,

```
-e trace=set
      Trace  only  the  specified set of system calls.  The -c option is
      useful for determining which  system  calls  might  be  useful  to
      trace.   For  example,  trace=open,close,read,write  means to only
      trace those four system calls.  Be careful when making  inferences
      about  the  user/kernel  boundary if only a subset of system calls
      are being monitored.  The default is trace=all.
```

In this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120345/31760), I use it to count the number of system calls. I don't know if anything will give you a summary breakdown of throughput, however strace can produce the figures for something like `awk` to summarise.

Comment: `strace` can slow things down significantly, so it's useful to measure relative times of different syscalls, but I would not use it as a general purpose timer.  `perf` is far faster/less intrusive, if you play with sampling frequency options.