# How to run parallel processes and combine outputs when both finished

Tags: scripting, parallelism

I have a bash shell script in which I pipe some data through about 5 or 6 different programs then the final results into a tab delimited file.

I then do the same again for a separate similar dataset and output to a second file.

Then both files are input into another program for comparative analysis.
e.g. to simplify

```
Data1 | this | that |theother | grep |sed | awk |whatever > Data1Res.csv
Data2 | this | that |theother | grep |sed | awk |whatever > Data2Res.csv
AnalysisProg -i Data1res.csv Data2res.csv
```

My question is : how can I make step1 and step2 run at the same time (e.g. using &) but only launch step3 (AnalysisProg) when both are complete?

thx

ps AnalysisProg will not work on a stream or fifo.

Comment: Check this: http://pebblesinthesand.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/a-srcipt-for-running-processes-in-parallel-in-bash/

Comment: BTW, is it ok for you to use Perl scripts? This can simplify the matter a lot for you and you can implement this post-processing very efficiently and make it run in parallel effortlessly.

Comment: Perl..not so much, no :(

Comment: Here i demonstrate how to split input across pipes with *`tee`* and process it with two concurrent *`grep`* processes: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120333/why-is-iterating-over-a-file-twice-faster-than-reading-it-into-memory-and-comput/120353#120353

Comment: And here i demonstrate how to use simple shell constructs to fully background a process in the way *`nohup`* might but still maintaining a means of communicating with the process: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121253/log-to-multiple-files-while-process-in-background-nohoup/121380#121380

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `wait`.  For example:

```
Data1 ... > Data1Res.csv &
Data2 ... > Data2Res.csv &
wait
AnalysisProg
```

will:

- run the Data1 and Data2 pipes as background jobs
- wait for them both to finish
- run AnalysisProg.

See, e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131484/wait-for-bash-background-jobs-in-script-to-be-finished).

Comment: Thx, that looks good. I'll try this if the above doesn't work.

Comment: Thx again, i was kind of aware of wait but having googled a bit was confused to how it worked with different PID etc.. I feel daft now I see it is just  "wait"

Answer (score 12):

cxw's answer is no doubt the preferable solution, if you only have 2 files. If the 2 files are just examples and you in reality have 10000 files, then the '&' solution will not work, as that will overload your server. For that you need a tool like GNU Parallel:

```
ls Data* | parallel 'cat {} | this | that |theother | grep |sed | awk |whatever > {}res.csv
AnalysisProg -i *res.csv
```

To learn more about GNU Parallel:

- Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1
- Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
  will love you for it.

Comment: Hi thx. At this time I do have two files, but I have 24 processors so I was feeling tempted to try and run many pairs at once - though as not a computing science person I'm unclear whether the disk reading bottleneck would make it worthwhile. maybe I'll suck it and see ;)

Comment: @StephenHenderson depending on size the files can still be in cache. If speed's critical you can just use tmpfs (and the files are <<< then your RAM).

Comment: @StephenHenderson The number of parallel jobs can be adjusted with -j, so try -j4 and if the server does not overload, try -j6 etc. But be ready to press CTRL-C: GNU Parallel is an excellent tool for overloading servers quickly. Also have a look at --load.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this could look something like :

```
AnalysisProg <<PREPROCESS /dev/stdin
$( 
{   process1=$( pipe | line | 1 >&2 & echo $! )
    process2=$( pipe | line | 2 >&2 & echo $! )
    while ps -p $process1 $process2 >/dev/null; do
        sleep 1
    done
} 2>&1
)
#END
PREPROCESS
```

In this way you background both pipelines but still wait for them to finish executing before combining their output into stdin which is evaluated in a here-document and handed to AnalysisProg. If you can use *`wait`* this is even better than the *`while ps`* loop, but, shell depending, *`wait`* can object if you instruct it to wait around on a process that **is not a child of the current shell.**

Also note that the above method will collate output - so both processes will be writing out at once. If you instead wanted them separate, or appended one to another possibly you could do:

```
AnalysisProg 3<<PREPROCESS /dev/fd/3 /dev/stderr
$(
process1=$(... >&2 ...) 2>/dev/fd/3
...
} 3>/dev/fd/3 2>/dev/stderr
)
```

I've demonstrated these concepts before. Probably the best demos are [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121253/log-to-multiple-files-while-process-in-background-nohoup/121380#121380) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120333/why-is-iterating-over-a-file-twice-faster-than-reading-it-into-memory-and-comput/120353#120353).

Answer (score 0):

Try use this.

```
rm -f Data1Res.csv
rm -f Data2Res.csv
Data1 | this | that |theother | grep |sed | awk |whatever > Data1Res.csv &
Data2 | this | that |theother | grep |sed | awk |whatever > Data2Res.csv &
while true
do
  ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -i -E 'Data1Res.csv|Data2Res.csv' &> /dev/null
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    AnalysisProg -i Data1res.csv Data2res.csv
    exit 0
  fi
done
```

Comment: Well that's an heavy one. Isn't it like reinventing `wait`'s wheel ?