# Cost of file Operation in Shell Script

Tags: shell, files

I just want to know, the file operation in shell script is expensive operation?. We can say, it is expensive in Java or other OOP languages(Need to call `open()` with read or write option and then we can read or write). But in shell script, we can redirect the output like `echo $line > /root/test.txt`
I cant see any overhead or expensive operation. Read is expensive or write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wouldn't notice much of a problem processing small files, out of interest you might like to read the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120333/why-is-iterating-over-a-file-twice-faster-than-reading-it-into-memory-and-comput/120345#120345).

Comment: If this answers your question, please, mark it as solved.